# Google Chart individual bar colours

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have read over numerous other questions regarding this and tried every code example provided but none work. I need to have individual colours for each bar, and this is the data I'm passing to the graph:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Count'],
    ['January 2009', 10],
    ['February 2009', 20],
    ['March 2009', 10],
    ['April 2009', 20],
    ['May 2009', 10],
    ['June 2009', 20],
    ['July 2009', 10],
    ['August 2009', 20],
    ['September 2009', 10],
    ['October 2009', 20],
    ['November 2009', 10],
    ['December 2009', 20]
]);
```

I've tried the method of setting data suggested here [Google Chart, different color for each bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375248/google-chart-diferent-color-for-each-bar?rq=1) but this doesn't seem to work with having string values on the X axis.

How would I go about having string X values, numeric Y values, and set the colours individually?

Ideally I'd also like to set the colour explicitly for each bar rather than just passing an array of colours, is this possible?

Comment: What would be the problem with having an array of colours (explicitly defined somewhere or computed by a function generating `N` distinct colours) and using that?

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do it is by creating a different series for each set of data. So rather than setting up your data like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Count'],
    ['January 2009', 10],
    ['February 2009', 20],
    ['March 2009', 10],
    ['April 2009', 20],
    ['May 2009', 10],
    ['June 2009', 20],
    ['July 2009', 10],
    ['August 2009', 20],
    ['September 2009', 10],
    ['October 2009', 20],
    ['November 2009', 10],
    ['December 2009', 20]
]);
```

You add a separate column for each set of data like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'],
    ['January 2009', 10, null, null, null],
    ['February 2009', null, 20, null, null],
    ['March 2009', null, null, 10, null],
    ['April 2009', null, null, null, 20],
]);
```

This will make each series a different color (it will also make each series and individual item in the legend, which may or may not be unappealing depending on your application).

You could write a for loop to go through your original data and add in the nulls automatically with something like this:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < rawData.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    data.addColumn('string', rawData.getFormattedValue(i, 0));
  };

  for (var j = 0; j < rawData.getNumberOfColumns() - 2; j++) {
    data.addRow();
    data.setValue(j, 0, rawData.getColumnLabel(j + 1));
    for (var i = 0; i < rawData.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      data.setValue(j, i + 1, rawData.getValue(i, j+1));
    };
  };
```

Adding a column will add all 'null' values, then you can just set the data values as you'd like. Without doing it in this relatively awkward way (adding all the extra series) there isn't any way to color the various series within the API.

If you don't want to do it this way, your best bet is to dig in to the SVG and figure out how to manipulate the SVG with CSS instead (this will cause browser compatibility issues with IE, however).